# Search indices in a dataframe with several conditions with findall() function

Tags: dataframe, select, conditional-statements, julia

in `Julia 1.3`

How is it possible to search items in a dataframe with several conditions. Here is an example with the `iris.csv` dataset (downloadable [here](https://gist.github.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7))

```
df = CSV.read(".../iris.csv");
df[1:6,:]

6 rows × 5 columns
    sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width species
    Float64 Float64 Float64 Float64 String
1   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
2   4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
3   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4   4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
5   5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
6   5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
```

Let's say I want to select the indices of rows with the sepal_length equal to 5.1:

```
findall(df[:,1] .== 5.1)

9-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
 18
 20
 22
 24
 40
 45
 47
 99
```

Same now with selecting indices with species "setosa":

```
findall(df[:,5] .== "setosa")[1:10]
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

Let's say now that I want to select the indices of rows with the sepal_length equal to 5.1 AND species "setosa" (I tried a similar syntax as the function `which()` in `R`):

```
findall(df[:,1] .== 5.1 & df[:,5] .== "setosa")

MethodError: no method matching &(::Float64, ::PooledArrays.PooledArray{String,UInt32,1,Array{UInt32,1}})
Closest candidates are:
  &(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...) at operators.jl:529

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[149]:1
```

Which command should I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to broadcast the `&` operator (note the parentheses and the dot before the `&`),

```
findall((df[:,1] .== 5.1) .& (df[:,5] .== "setosa"))
```

Note, however, that `df[:,1] .== 5.1` and `df[:,5] .== "setosa"` both allocate temporary arrays. Consider using the version of `findall` which takes a function as the first argument like so:

```
findall(x -> x.sepal.length == 5.1 && x.species == "setosa", eachrow(df))
```